# Variable frequency for sine wave in Verilog

Tags: verilog, simulation, vivado, testbench

I am trying to implement 4 different frequencies at which sine wave is going to be simulated in testbench. I am using a counter to do so. However, it can not toggle clk_out in simulation window. Not sure where the error is.

[image]

Code:

```
module functionGenerator(Clk,data_out, reg0, clk_out);
//declare input and output
    input Clk;
    output [9:0] data_out;
    output reg clk_out;  
    input [3:0] reg0;
    reg [31:0] constantNumber;  
    reg [9:0] sine [0:99];
    integer i;  
    reg [9:0] data_out;
    reg [31:0] count;
//Initialize the sine rom with samples. 
    initial begin
        i = 0;
        clk_out = 0;

        sine[0] = 0;        sine[1] = 10;        sine[2] = 20;        sine[3] = 29;        sine[4] = 39;   
        sine[5] = 48;       sine[6] = 58;        sine[7] = 67;        sine[8] = 75;        sine[9] = 84;
        sine[10] = 92;      sine[11] = 100;      sine[12] = 107;      sine[13] = 114;      sine[14] = 120;
        sine[15] = 126;     sine[16] = 132;      sine[17] = 137;      sine[18] = 141;      sine[19] = 145;   
        sine[20] = 149;     sine[21] = 151;      sine[22] = 153;      sine[23] = 155;      sine[24] = 156;
        sine[25] = 156;

    end


    always @ (reg0)
    begin
        if(reg0 == 4'b0000)
            constantNumber = 50;
        else if(reg0 == 4'b0001)
            constantNumber = 100;
        else if(reg0 == 4'b0010)
            constantNumber = 200;
        else if(reg0 == 4'b0100)
            constantNumber = 300;
        else if(reg0 == 4'b1000)
            constantNumber = 400;
        else
            constantNumber = 500;
    end

    always @ (posedge(Clk))
    begin        
        if (count == constantNumber - 1)
            begin
            count <= 32'b0;
            end
        else
            begin
            count <= count + 1;
            end
    end

    always @ (posedge(Clk))
    begin
        if (count == constantNumber - 1)
            clk_out <= ~clk_out;
        else
            clk_out <= clk_out;
    end   

    //At every change in clk_out state, output a sine wave sample.
    always@ (clk_out)
        begin
            if ( i < 25 )
               data_out = sine[i];
            else if ( i < 50 )
               data_out = sine[50 - i];
            else if  ( i < 75 )
               data_out = - sine[i - 50];
            else 
               data_out = - sine[100 - i];
            i = i+ 1;
            if(i == 100)
                i = 0;
    end
endmodule
```

and Test bench:

```
module functionGeneratror_tb();

    // Inputs
    reg Clk;
    reg reg0;
    wire clk_out;
    // Outputs
    wire [9:0] data_out;

    // Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
    functionGenerator uut (
        .Clk(Clk), 
        .data_out(data_out),
        .reg0(reg0),
        .clk_out(clk_out)

    );

    //Generate a clock with 10 ns clock period.
    initial
    begin 
    Clk = 0;
    reg0 = 4'b0000;
    end
    always #5 Clk = ~Clk; 

endmodule
```

Comment: Exactly how does the simulation fail? If there are any errors or warnings in the console, copy them into your question.

Comment: I edited the question. The simulation executes but the waveform is wrong.

Comment: In your code, you have a comment saying you want to do something on every *positive* edge of `clk_out`, but then the code does something on every edge, going either way.

Comment: Yes sorry, i had it essentially checking each clk pos edge but now i want  to do combinational logic.

Comment: As combinatorial logic, your code is equivalent to connecting a NOT gate between `clk_out` and itself, enabled whenever the count condition is met. You have no control over how many times `clk_out` toggles during the cycle of `Clk` when the count condition is met.

Comment: @ThePhoton is there a way to fix it? Cause I am fairly confused now.

Comment: I did initialize the clk_out but it just remains constant throughout the entire simulation cycle.

Comment: Where did you initialize it? I don't see it in the posted code.

Comment: If you have additional information related to your original question, use the "edit" button to add the information there. It was put "on hold" in order to allow you to improve it before people try to answer it. Do not create a duplicate question.

Comment: @ThePhoton I edited the code above.

Comment: Now you have to simulate millions of cycles of `Clk` before you'd expect `clk_out` to do anything. Try changing `constantNumber` to 10 or something if you don't want to wait all day for your simulation to finish.

Comment: @ThePhoton I did change for all of the cases, but clk_out doesn't toggle at all just remains constant

Answer (score 1):

You never initialized `clk_out`, so the initial value is `x`.

Then you keep toggling `clk_out`, but since the simulator doesn't know the initial value, the value after toggling is still `x`.

You can resolve this by initializing `clk_out`, either in the declaration, in an initial block, or by defining a reset condition in the always block that controls it (which will work for synthesis but I'm not 100% sure it will work in simulation).

Also, I noticed another issue,

> ```
> //At every positive edge of the clock, output a sine wave sample.
> always@ (clk_out)
> ```

Your comment says you want to respond to positive edges, but your code says to respond to **all** edges.

The code is probably not synthesizable.

Comment: I changed it already. It was sequential logic before, but combinational here is used instead.